# I want to take an input and use it as a parameter of a function in javascript

Tags: javascript, function, alert, prompt, parsefloat

```js
function myfunc(num,fix) {
  alert(num.toFixed(fix));
}
myfunc(2.222, 2);
```

In the above code, 2.222 and 2 are hard-coded. I want to take these values from a user. I have tried the following solution but it seems that it can be run without parameters being involved.

```js
let num_new = prompt("Enter a decimal number");
let num = parseFloat(num_new);
let fix = prompt("Enter the decimal places to be rounded");

function myfunc(num, fix) {
  alert(num.toFixed(fix));
}
myfunc(num, fix);
```

the above code can also run by removing the parameters, I need help in finding out a solution in which the parameters are being input from user. Thanks alot

Comment: So, the question is how to check the values returned from the prompts?

Comment: The code is getting the parameters from user input. What are you asking?

Comment: the code is running even if i omit the parameters, it is taking the values from outside of function and use it inside function, @Barmar

Comment: Do you mean if you write `function myfunc() { alert(num.toFixed(fix)); }`?

Comment: If you don't declare parameters, it treats them as global variables. There's no way to prevent that. Just make sure you always declare the parameters.

Comment: Yes Sir @Barmar

Comment: Thank you Sir @Barmar

Comment: You can use tools like ESLint to check your code for mistakes like that.

Comment: Your question was improved twice, why did you roll it back?

Comment: I accidentally did it @terrymorse, sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

You can try using default values for your parameters. Like

```js
document.addEventListener("click", handleBttnClick)

function myFunc(
  // if user input is not a number, defaults to 0.0
  num = parseFloat(prompt("Enter a decimal number")) || 0.0,
  // if user input is not a number, defaults to 2
  fix = parseInt(prompt("Enter the decimal places to be rounded")) || 2) {
  console.log(num.toFixed(fix));
}

function handleBttnClick(evt) {
  if (evt.target.nodeName === "BUTTON") {
    console.clear();
    switch (evt.target.id) {
      case "prompt":
        return myFunc();
      case "fromNumberInput":
        {
          const value = 
            parseFloat(document.querySelector("#inputsinglefloat").value) || 0.0;
          return myFunc(value);
        }
      case "allFromInput":
        {
          const value = 
            parseFloat(document.querySelector("#inputfloat").value) || 0.0;
          const decimals = 
            parseInt(document.querySelector("#inputdecimals").value) || 2;
          return myFunc(value, decimals);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<button id="prompt">prompt</button> for values
<p>
  <input type="number" 
    value="3.141592653589793238462643383279" 
    id="inputsinglefloat"> type a number
  <button id="fromNumberInput">round</button>
</p>

<p>
  <input type="number"
    value="3.141592653589793238462643383279" 
    id="inputfloat"> type a number
  <input type="number" value="2" id="inputdecimals"> n of decimals
  <button id="allFromInput">round</button>
</p>
```

Comment: dear @Kooilnc, what is the usage of " ||0.0 " and " ||2 "

Comment: See the comments above it. It's called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation). I added some code to the snippet to demonstrate several usages of `myFunction`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="myfunc()">click</button>
    <script>
        function myfunc() {
            let firstval = '';
            let secondval = '';
            let newFirstVal = prompt("Enter First value:", firstval);
            let newSecondVal = prompt("Enter Second value:", secondval);
            if (newFirstVal === "" && newSecondVal === "") {
                alert("you should enter both values")
            } else if (newFirstVal === "" && newSecondVal !== "") {
                alert("you should enter newFirstVal values")
            } else if (newFirstVal !== "" && newSecondVal === "") {
                alert("you should enter newSecondVal values")
            } else {
                alert(parseFloat(newFirstVal).toFixed(newSecondVal));
            }
        }

    </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: there is no function declaration, how it will work with function? @mohammad mohammadi nodhe